# Vue transitions

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions

Dear developers, I have a question. Below code from Vue comonent

```
<transition-group name="fading">
        <div v-for="item, id in b_data" :id="id" :dataName="item" v-if="address == item" class="card-body transition" key="d">
          <p class="text-info align-middle">{{ item }} address</p>
        </div>
        </transition-group>
```

and this is code does't work. But if I change v-if to v-show all work properly. Why?

Code with v-show

```
<transition-group name="fading">
        <div v-for="item, id in b_data" :id="id" :dataName="item" v-if="address == item" class="card-body transition" key="d">
          <p class="text-info align-middle">{{ item }} address</p>
        </div>
        </transition-group>
```

and css code:

```
.fading-enter,
  .fading-leave-to
  {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .fading-enter-active
  {
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
    animation: bounce-in 1s;
  }

  .fading-leave-active
  {
    animation: bounce-in 1s reverse;
  }

  @keyframes bounce-in {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(1.5);
      opacity: .5;
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: .2;
    }
  }
```

What I doing wrong? Why v-if doesn't work?

Comment: Try `v-if="(item, id) in b_data"`. Also, each root item needs a `key` if you're using `transition-group`.

Comment: @B.Fleming thank you for the answer. But, as you can see <div> tag keyed already.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice it when I replied initially. I do notice, however, that the `key` is not a unique value. It should be unique for list transitions per the documentation. If `id` is unique, consider using `:key="id"` or, if you intend to use `id` as a key elsewhere as well and it produces a conflict, something like `:key="'card-body-' + id"` could also work (basing it on one of the element's classes for the sake of the example).

Comment: @B.Fleming Cool! You're really help me. It works. Many thanks!